# .Net MVC API Access-Control-Allow-Origin error upon Ajax POST request

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, api

I have a .Net solution in VS2013, with multiple project on separate ports. I am sending data back and forth between two of these projects, mainly an API project on `localhost:4348` and a front-end project on `localhost:33630`.

I am using jQuery to make ajax calls to the API and sending data through the POST request, an example of the POST request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://localhost:4348/api/Viewer/GetSearchResult',
    data: searchObject,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(responseData);
    },
    error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("Text status:", textStatus);
    }
});
```

The searchObject structure is as follows, where its items get populated at some point before the ajax call:

```
searchObject.generalSearchList = [];
searchObject.indexesSearchList = [];
searchObject.searchType = '';
searchObject.language = '';
searchObject.id = '';
searchObject.selector = '';
```

The API project does not allow me to add the followings settings to Web.config file:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Doing that raises this error on any API I try to call:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://localhost:4348/api/Viewer/GetTrees?Lang=en-US`. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '`http://localhost:33630`, *', but only one is allowed. Origin '`http://localhost:33630`' is therefore not allowed access.

So without that option set, when I try to call the API with `POST` method, I get the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://localhost:4348/api/Viewer/GetSearchResult`. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '`http://localhost:33630`' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

Having the `contentType` set to `application/json; charset=utf-8` fires a preflight request of type `OPTIONS`.
Somewhere along the lines of Visual Studio, it is adding permission to the origin `http://localhost:33630` on `GET` requests, but not on `OPTIONS` requests. And I cannot override the permission as I mentioned in the Web.config file.

I have done a lot of research and tested many scenarios before posting here, including adding

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
```

to the web.config file in the API project.

Needless to say I am desperate to understand the cause of the error and solving it as I have been stuck with this for about a week now. Tested on Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable CORS in your WebApiConfig.cs also.

1. Install nuget [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors/5.2.3)
2. Enable cors in WebApiConfig.cs

   ```
   public static class WebApiConfig
   {
       public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
       {
           var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
           config.EnableCors(cors);
           // Other config lines
       }
   }
   ```

This will enable CORS gloablly, you can decorate your api controller or even single api method with

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    // Controller methods not shown...
}
```

to target specific controllers or method.
You can read more about enabling CORS in WebAPI projects at 
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: I was hoping to know why visual studio is adding permission from within itself. I have stumbled upon installing the cors package but it raised compatibility issues with other packages in the solution. I will try this again and get back to you. Thanks for your efforts.